# how to use weka to normalize instances

Tags: java, weka, normalization

I'd like to know to to apply weka to normalize my dataset.

```
BufferedReader reader;
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
dataset = new Instances(reader);
```

What should I do next?

Comment: You should put that as an answer and accept it!  That way people will see it is solved, and it may help people in the future.

Comment: Thanks Walter, i am new here and was unable to answer my own question yesterday. Now i have posted my answer but still that can only be accepted tomorrow

Comment: I posted the working Java example with K-Means here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271203/weka-normalizing-columns/46291993#46291993

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Normalize filter = new Normalize();
filter.setInputFormat(data);
dataset = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);
```

Comment: 1 upvote for correct solution. But, what's corresponding to "nomialToBinary" filter in the parameter setting?